# clearIntveral not functioning for some reason

Tags: javascript, html

So I tried creating an interval where users are able to toggle it. For some reason, the interval isn't stopping.

```js
        var num = 0;
        var playing = true;
    
        function hello(){
            var playInterval = setInterval(() => {
                document.querySelector("#test").innerHTML = num;
                num += 1;
            }, 200);
            if (playing == false) {
                playing = true;
            } else{
                playing = false;
                // Why is it not clearing the interval?
                clearInterval(playInterval);
            }
    
        }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 id="test"></h1>
        <button onclick="hello()">Play</button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

How could this be achieved?

Comment: If you trigger the `hello()` function twice, how many times will `setInterval` be called? And how many are you clearing?

Comment: I tried clearInterval(playInterval) twice that doesn't work also. Do you have any way to make it stop?

Comment: And consider what the scope of `var playInterval` is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When play button pressed check is currently playing. if not playing create new interval and set button `innerHTML` to `pause`. if button pressed again and is playing `clearInterval` and set button `innerHTML` to `resume`.

```js
const test = document.querySelector("#test")

const button = document.querySelector('#button')

let num = 0;
let isPlaying = false;
let playInterval;

function hello() {
  if (!isPlaying) {
    button.innerHTML = 'pause'

    playInterval = setInterval(() => {
      test.innerHTML = num;
      num += 1;
    }, 200);
  } else {
    button.innerHTML = 'resume'

    clearInterval(playInterval);
  }

  isPlaying = !isPlaying
}
```

```html
<h1 id="test"></h1>
<button onclick="hello()" id="button">Play</button>
```

Comment: Yep, although your answer has been accepted. It may not be obvious what you have done. Please add an explanation of what was causing the problem and how you've fixed it in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to declare `playInterval` in the global scope (outside of the function)

Comment: Yes that may be a possibility, but how does the interval start again?

Comment: By clicking the button again. In the function should be `playInterval = setInterval(() => {...})` (not `var playInterval`)

Answer (score 0):

The first click sets `playing` to `false`. The next click therefore doesn't clear the interval.

Comment: Please read the code again. Because playing is already true it should clear the interval.

Comment: `playing` is true on the first click. On the second click it is false..